# NVDA + JAB + Swing is not responsive on hover events on swing components

Tags: java, swing, screen-readers, nvda

I encountered the problem when developing swing application with NVDA, that NVDA only reads the accessible content I assgined to the component ( In my case a toggle button ) when I fire a click on that component, but what I am looking for is NVDA to start reading when I have my mouse over it.

I actually have seen it working ( NVDA reads on mouse over component ) on someone others laptop, so it convinced me I must have something mis-configured, but both laptops ( mine and the working one ) installed NVDA using default options and follows the same procedure to install jaccess to jre.

I have been struggling with this issue for days and feel painful trying to resolve the problem, I will be so grateful if someone could help

Im using openJdk7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

It is related to my workstation setup. I got a laptop and an external monitor, and I'm used to get all works done in the bigger monitor while leaving the laptop screen open for mails client.

Laptop's own monitor is set to be the main display in windows.

It takes me days figure out what actually happens was NVDA + JAB + Swing is not responsive on hover events on swing components in my **secondary** monitor. But when I drag my swing application to the **primary** monitor, all things worked, magically.

Hope my comments would be helpful to who else encountering a similar case.